# How to receive touch event behind another view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have two subviews inside the view. The frame is equal. A view has a swipe left gesture recognizer and B view has a swipe right gesture recognizer. B is behind A so I can only trigger swipe left gesture. How can I receive both?

Comment: add swipegesture recongnizer to window. and then you need to handle swipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The view in the back will not respond because, well, it's in the back.
2. For both gestures to respond simultaneously (left+right at the same time), add a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to either and handle `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` as suggested below.
3. If you want B to respond to a gesture, even though it is partially hidden by A, rethink your hierarchy: add a 3rd view above A & B (call it C), same size as B, as a placeholder to your gesture recognizer.

Your delegate:

```
// leftGesture
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer
    *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return otherGestureRecognizer == rightGesture;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying, but it's not what I want. I edit the post.

Comment: Views hierarchy + gestures go hand in hand. In accordance to your drawing, A is above B ; If you want the hidden part of B to respond to a selector, your best bet is to create an invisible view, C, the same size+dimension as B, and have it float above A.

Comment: Fix **this** question so that it matches the answer : You now have an approved response with an orphaned question. Then write **another** post with your edit.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I receive both?

Add both gesture recognizers to view A, since that's the view in front. Since you need the right swipe gesture to be handled by view B, make view B the target for the right swipe gesture recognizer.

A better option might be to make your view controller the target of both gesture recognizers and let it sort out what to do with the user's gestures. That helps to get the views out of the business of knowing how the user interface is set up -- they just have to follow instructions from the view controller. If you adopt that plan, your view controller might look like this in part:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UISwipeGestureController *leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureController alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipe:)];
    leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft; 
    UISwipeGestureController *rightSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureController alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipe:)];
    rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

    [self.viewA addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];
    [self.viewA addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe];
}

- (IBAction)leftSwipe:(id)sender
{
    [self.viewA doSomething];
}

- (IBAction)rightSwipe:(id)sender
{
    [self.viewB doSomethingElse];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying, but it's not what I want. I edit the post to clarify my question.

Comment: I'm afraid your edit is very difficult to understand, and it's far from clear why you'd want to do things that way. Further explanation is necessary.

Comment: I add more details with screenshot. Sorry for my unclear explanation.